# Get the contents of a particular tab (Firefox add-on development)

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm working on a Firefox add-on, and with it, I need to monitor the contents of a particular site and react to DOM changes. Currently, I'm using a combination of `gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("class")` and attaching a `DOMSubteeeModified` event to it. But I notice that it works only when the tab is active. When I'm away using another tab, and the DOM changes in the inactive tab, it does not work. How do I get around this? The Firefox MDN is pretty scattered (and sometimes outdated), it is very frustrating for a newbie.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```js
var MyExtension = {
    init() : function() {
        if("gBrowser" in window) {
            gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e){this.onPageLoad(e);},false);
        },

   onPageLoad: function(e) {
       var doc = e.originalTarget;
       if((/http://xxxx.xyz/v/[0-9a-z]/).test(doc.location.href)) {
           MyExtension.XXX.handler(e);
       }
       e.originalTarget.defaultView.addEventListener("unload", function(e){MyExtension.onUnload(e);}, false);
   },

   onUnload: function(e) {
       if((/http://xxxx.xyz/v/[0-9a-z]/).test(e.originalTarget.location.href)) {
           //remove listeners and nullify references to dom objects
   }
};

MyExtension.XXX = {
    handler : function(e) {
        //get dom element with gBrowser.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("class");
        //bind DOMSubtreeModified listener, attach a function to handle the event
    }
};

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    window.removeEventListener("load", load, false);
    MyExtension.init();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the technique I'm following, using `gBrowser.selectedBrowser` as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_tab_selection)

```
var MyExtension = {
    tab : null, //<---- added this line
    init() : function() {
        if("gBrowser" in window) {
            gBrowser.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e){this.onPageLoad(e);},false);
    },

    onPageLoad: function(e) {
       var doc = e.originalTarget;
       if((/http://xxxx.xyz/v/[0-9a-z]/).test(doc.location.href)) {
           this.tab = gBrowser.selectedBrowser; //<--- GET REFERENCE TO CURRENT TAB
           MyExtension.XXX.handler(e);
       }
       e.originalTarget.defaultView.addEventListener("unload", function(e){MyExtension.onUnload(e);}, false);
    },

    onUnload: function(e) {
       if((/http://xxxx.xyz/v/[0-9a-z]/).test(e.originalTarget.location.href)) {
           //remove listeners and nullify references to dom objects
       }
    };

    MyExtension.XXX = {
        handler : function(e) {
        //get dom element
        MyExtension.tab.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("class"); //<--- GET CONTENT DOCUMENT INSIDE DESIRED TAB
        //bind DOMSubtreeModified listener, attach a function to handle the event
    }
};
```